# Pure Html/CSS US Phone Number input

Tags: html, css, forms

Just be clear I am not asking about validation,just pure layout. I am trying to display  three separate input fields with a dash in between. Here is a link to what I have so far. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kCNA4/
Here's my question is there a better way of doing this, am I doing it completion wrong or is the Way I wrote it correct. Thanks so much.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  You might want to consider using a different dash between the boxes, specifically `&#8211;`.

Comment: Oh also, you may have tried this already but a lot of UI people really like flush-left forms, labeled just like yours but (in this case) with "Last Name" down under "First Name" instead of off to the right. Personally, I'm ambivalent.

Comment: @pointy I am working off of a PSD but I think I read that somewhere as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty good to me - agree with comment, – should be used for hyphen, only a couple of improvements I would add. One, input type number (I know you are not worried about validation now) as HTML 5 input type definition. Also, use unique name for field so that when it is posted, you can identify the output.

```
<input type="number" value="" maxlength="3" name="phoneNumberFirst" id="mainFormPhoneFirst">
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just one question are you sure I should use use unique names for the phone number even though its all part of the same phone number.

Comment: When it gets read by some server script - it will treat them as all separate input boxes and it is the responsibility of the server script to put it all together into one variable. So yes, they need different names, or possibly to be named as an array if the server side language supports it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the facets about phone number entry is that there is a better 'type' available which many feature phones and mobile web browsers provide unique, number-only entry methods for.

```
<input type="tel" ... />
```

If you want just numeric input, this seems to be a great way to "force" that for mobile browsers (there's probably a workaround or doesn't work for all mobile browsers). You'll still need to filter and validate the input but I feel that the experience is going to be better for the mobile user.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this simple input filed tags like this:

```
<input type="tel" name="tel1" title="3-digit" maxlength="3" minlength="3" size="3"/> -
<input type="tel" name="tel2" title="3-digit" maxlength="3" minlength="3" size="3"/> - 
<input type="tel" name="tel3" title="4-digit" maxlength="4" minlength="4" size="4"/>
```